# Can I use FirebaseMessaging.framework without `use_frameworks!`?

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using cocoapods 
1.1.0.beta.1 Latest one.

and trying to install

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'AFNetworking'

 target 'XXX_Example' do
  pod 'XXX', :path => '../'

  target 'XXX_Tests' do
      inherit! :search_paths

  end
end
```

[!] The 'Pods-XXX_Example' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX/XXXSDK/XXX-ios/Example/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework)

Please let me know how can i resolve it?

thanks,

Comment: I don't want to comment use_frameworks!, this will work without it but in future, when i try to install another swift library then it gives me google static library issues.

Comment: use_frameworks is not necessary, it is a convenience for easy importing by swift developers. You should be able to remove use_frameworks if you see the need.

Comment: yes, i can do that but if i download it from cocoapods then only i got issue like in TKKeyboardControl

Comment: So do the other libs you are using require use_frameworks?

Comment: yes some other also need use_frameworks? actually, when someone creates use_frameworks create framework for that particular pod.